# ER_DUP_ENTRY even after checking if key exists using SELECT

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I have an array with records that I want to put into MYSQL database from NodeJS. These records have a jobkey field that I want to be UNIQUE, but I don't want it to be the PRIMARY KEY since the jobkey coming from an API and I want to use my own recid for better indexing and sorting.

I am using NodeJS to first check if the jobkey exists by doing a SELECT WHERE and checking if rows.length > 0? then adding the job if jobkey does not already exist. For some reason I keep getting a ER_DUP_ENTRY error and I can't figure out why my rows.length sometimes === 0 even though the jobkey exists. I have been hitting my head against the wall now for a few days. I hope it's not just a semi-colon or one of those simple errors I have overlooked. Anyways I need help please look at my code.

```
function is_job_key(_jobkey, cb){ // cb(err, flag)
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_indeed WHERE ?';
  conn.query(sql, {jobkey: _jobkey}, function(err, rows){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return cb(true);
    }
    bar.tick();
    if(rows.length > 0){ // jobkey exists
      return cb(null, true);
    }
    cb(null, false);
  });
}
function insert_job(posts, cb){ // cb(err)
  var sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_indeed SET ?';
  conn.query(sql, posts, function(err, result){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return cb(true);
    }
    bar.tick();
    cb(null);
  });
}
function insert_all_jobs(job_arr, query_str, cb){ // cb(err, count_inserted)
  function get_posts(job){
    var posts = {jobkey: job.jobkey, snippet: job.snippet, url: job.url, jobtitle: job.jobtitle, company: job.company, date: job.date, query_string: query_str};
    return posts;
  }
  bar = new progress('  ' + query_str + ' (:current / :total) [:bar] :percent :etas', {
    complete: '=',
    incomplete: ' ',
    width: 40,
    total: job_arr.length*2
  });
  var count_inserted = 0;
  async.each(job_arr, function(job, cb){
    var posts = get_posts(job);
    is_job_key(job.jobkey, function(err, result){
      if(err) return cb(true);
      if(result){
        bar.tick();
        return cb(); // jobkey exists
      }
      insert_job(posts, function(err){
        if(err) return cb(true);
        count_inserted++;
        cb();
      });
    });
  }, function(err){
    if(err) return cb(true);
    console.log('done');
    conn.end();
    cb(null, count_inserted);
  });
}
var job_arr = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('technician.txt', 'utf-8'));
//job_arr = job_arr.splice(1, 10); //for some reason this works ok...
insert_all_jobs(job_arr, 'technician', function(err, result){
  if(err) return console.log('error');
  console.log(result);
});
```

thank you for reading my question and have a lovely day
~A

Comment: if i splice the arr to something smaller it doesn't give me any errors at all...i'm not sure why but it's a temporarily solution. So far I have tried them in 100 record chunks without error

Comment: i guess a simple solution would be to not even check if the jobkey exists and just try to insert all the jobs, then catch the ER_DUP_ENTRY errors. might even be faster than doing it my way. i would still like a solution tho...